BTRFS not mounting, only one good superblock remaining
I've tried every btrfs tool I can find documentation for to try and mount and recover a KVM/QEMU virtual drive. I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to mount a drive with only one good superblock?
$ btrfs rescue super-recover -v /dev/vda2
ERROR: superblock checksum mismatch
ERROR: superblock checksum mismatch
ERROR: superblock checksum mismatch
All Devices:
    Device: id = 1, name = /dev/vda2

ERROR: superblock checksum mismatch
ERROR: superblock checksum mismatch
Before Recovering:
    [All good supers]:
        device name = /dev/vda2
        superblock bytenr = 274877906944

    [All bad supers]:
        device name = /dev/vda2
        superblock bytenr = 65536

        device name = /dev/vda2
        superblock bytenr = 67108864


Make sure this is a btrfs disk otherwise the tool will destroy other fs, Are you sure? [y/N]: y
parent transid verify failed on 971849728 wanted 62052 found 61780
parent transid verify failed on 971849728 wanted 62052 found 61780
ERROR: could not setup extent tree
Failed to recover bad superblocks 

Maybe it's possible to only recover files from a directory without mounting it? This is non-critical data so if it's dead, all good. I just wanted to see if I can save it for when it counts in the future.
